# Mongoose check value from other schema while findAndUpdate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Am I able to check a value from other mongo schema while findAndUpdate?

**Example:**

Schema 1:

```js
{ _id: 'myId1', name: 'test' }
```

Schema 2:

```js
{ _id: 'myId2', name: 'test-rest', connectedId: [ 'myId1' ] }
```

Now I want to check if connectedId has value name while updating

```js
await MongoModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { 
     _id: "myId",
     connectedId: { connectedValue.name === 'test' } // Now I want check if value from this connectedId has a value equal to my value
  },
  {
    name: "changeName"
  }
)
```

Comment: No this will not work. You'll need to query for the ID first, separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I completely overlooked that you also wanted to update the referenced document. I will howeever leave this answer in case someone else finds it useful.

You should checkout [populate from Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions). You can add references to other models like this when defining your schema:

```
connected: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'OtherModelName' }]
```

OtherModelName should match with however you name your other model when calling `mongoose.model('OtherModelName', yourSchema);` After that, you can `populate` the field with some conditions. This example is from the aforementioned documentation:

```
Story.
  find().
  populate({
    path: 'fans',
    match: { age: { $gte: 21 } },
    // Explicitly exclude `_id`
    select: 'name -_id'
  }).
  exec();
```

In your case, it would be something like

```
YourModel
  .find()
  .populate({
    path: 'connected',
    match: {name: 'test'}
  })
  .exec();
```